# Pactical limits to `ulimit -s 1048576`?

Tags: linux, memory, stack

Linux allows `ulimit -s unlimited`, which allows programs to exhaust system memory and crash the computer. So, generally no good.

But what are the drawbacks to a significantly higher limit to the current 8192 default, like `limit -s 1048576`? On a trusted computer, other than having many run-away programs/threads that combine together to exhaust memory, what's bad or undesirable that can happen?

Comment: What is the amount of concurrent users on that system ? ( ==1 or > 1) ? In case of > 1 is there something like a "typical" workload ?

Comment: Exhausting memory will not crash the computer. It will make subsequent memory allocations fail. The attempt to reach that state will call out-of-memory killer into action, which will kill the RAM-eating process. Not crash your computer. There's nothing special about eating memory for your stack vs eating memory for your heap. So, your whole question's premise might be incorrect... Does your question still stand?

Comment: Also I think your 8192 is not the default on Linux for more than a decade, but I'm not sure

Comment: @MarcusMüller 8192 is the soft limit today on all distributions I've tried. You can increase it, but you have to _explicitly_ increase it.

Answer (score 1):

ulimit has a hard and softlimit.  the hard limit for stack space is generally higher.  For example on my system, using the distro defaults:

```bash
$ ulimit -S -s
8192
$ ulimit -H -s
unlimited
```

There really isn't any reason to change the soft limit by default.   And it could cause wasted memory.  If stack space is of concern to a particular process, it should be launched via a wrapper shell script that raises the soft limit for that process only.   Hardlimits can be raised globally or per user/group membership as part of system configuration.

If you actually have real resource constraints, per process limits that ulimit provides really isn't a good mechanism.  I would look at another technology like solaris zones, control groups (containers), or vms.

is there ever a reason for higher softlimits?  Sure, things like number of filedescriptors were kept low due to keeping software that didn't work with large numbers of open files, and it can be annoying for people to have to constantly revise the soft limits.

Last thing worth mentioning is that when you use ulimit without the soft and hard settings you are actually changing both settings at once.  It's best to use -S when changing the setting so you don't accidently lower the hard limit.

Here is a demonstration of that.

```bash
$ ulimit -n
1024
$ ulimit -H -n
524288
$ ulimit -S -n
1024
$ ulimit -n 2048
$ ulimit -H -n
2048
$ ulimit -S -n
2048
```